# How to decide what should be the correct height of bicycle and its seat height would be appropriate for me?

Tags: weight-loss, bicycling

I want to buy a new bicycle which I would use to go to office and occasionally for longer rides. and my aim to reduce the weight as well as enjoy bicycling by going with groups to different kind of places, Jungle, hills, Road tours etc.

How to buy the bicycle where I can sit with correct posture? My weight is 115 kg and heigh is 5 foot 11 inch.

Should I buy geared or non geared bicycle?

Should I buy a bicycle with thin or think tyres?

Comment: This is probably a better fit (no pun intended) on the bicycle stack exchange.

Comment: I came here to say what John did. [http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) can do a way better job than we can.

Comment: This question belongs on bicycling.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding gears, yes if you are planning on cycling on varying inclines and terrains then you will need gears.

Also regarding tyres, for road cycling you are better with a smoother thinner tyre, do off-road cycling (like in the woods etc) you would need thicker tyres with deeper grooves.  I'm not sure where you live, but in the UK you can buy "hybrid" tyres that are suitable for both (but not optimised for one or the other).

As Michael suggests below, the absolute best thing is to visit a bike shop and actually sit on the bike, see how it feels and ask for advice from the staff while you are there as they will be used to this sort of question.  You can buy bikes with different frame sizes and wheel sizes.  Attached is a guide found on this web site www.halfords.com which is a popular motor and cycling chain.

[image: Bike Size Guide]

Comment: It also helps to clarify if you are talking about a road bike, touring bike, mountain bike, etc. Most of the time frame sizes are measured by length of the top tube in cm, not by inches.

Answer (score -1):

You have to sit on the actual seat and see for yourself Jitendra. A good rule of thumb is when you are seated on the bike that one of your legs is able to hang completely straight with no bend and hook into the pedal.

Hope that helps,

Mike

Comment: This is bad advice. If your leg is completely straight at the bottom of the pedal stroke, then either your seat is raised too high or the bike is too big. (Or possibly you have crank arms that are too long, but that is not a primary suspect). Bad position can create knee and hip problems.

Comment: I will defer to you John.